# Modulus of Elasticity

Tags: classical-mechanics

A new bulb with a bayonet fitting is to be inserted into a standard lamp. The mass of the bulb is 40 grams. To insert the bulb it is first placed in the holder so that it rests on the pi9ns. It then has to be pushed down 6mm against the pins and twisted; then, when it is released, it rises 2mm and is held firm by the pins in the slots in the holder. The maximum force you need to exert during the process is 2N. Find the force holding the bulb in position.

I have no idea on how to approach this question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force is proportional to deformation of the spring. Bulb mass plays  no role.

$$ 2 \cdot \dfrac { 6-2 }  { 6 } = 1. 333 N $$